# Stop '@' in alias name preventing bash completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

On one laptop I have bash aliases for ssh-ing into various machines of the form

```
loris@machineA
loris@machineB
```

On this machine I can type

```
loris@<TAB>
```

and bash will show me possible completions.

I have recently setup a second laptop running the same OS as the first (Debian 11) with the same aliases.  However when I try to get bash to complete the alias on the second laptop, I am offered things like

```
@ip6-allnodes    @ip6-allrouters  @ip6-localhost   @ip6-loopback    @localhost
```

Does anyone know what is going on and how I can get completion to work as it does on first laptop?

Comment: Maybe it checks `~/.ssh/known_hosts` besides `/etc/hosts`? Try connecting to a machine once from the second laptop and check whether it gets added to the completion list.

Comment: The '@' doesn't pose any problem on Ubuntu 22.04
To try, I added the following to my .bashrc:
alias me@home='cd /home/$(whoami)'
After sourcing it,
me@<TAB> successfully completes the alias.
Can you try that and give the result?

Comment: I already have connected to the machines by just writing out the alias in full.  The ```me@home``` example has the same problem on the second laptop.  So it is just to do with the ```@``` in the alias name.

Comment: Are you using gnome-terminal? If yes, please give the result of the following command: gnome-terminal --version
(in my case it gives: # GNOME Terminal 3.44.0 using VTE 0.68.0 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD) Oh, and add the bash version (bash --version) for info (5.1.16 in my case)

Comment: @loris Why not using `~/.ssh/config`? It would be way easier to define aliases there and Bash would autocomplete them, and it's the standard way to do so

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I probably should do that.  However, regardless of what the alias is for, I am still interested in why ```@``` in the alias name breaks completion.

Comment: @S_Bersier The versions of gnome-terminal are the same on both laptops, namely 3.38.4, and the problem also occurs if I use xterm.  The bash version is 5.1.4(1).

Comment: Could you check in synaptic (or the equivalent on Debian) if bash-completion is installed? If not, install it with:  sudo apt install bash-completion EDIT: Maybe you have to reboot to make it effective.

Comment: @S_Bersier Well spotted!  Installing the package```bash-completion``` solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Debian is just a slightly leaner distro, I suppose.  Since vanilla bash does do some completion by itself, maybe it was felt that the extra package wasn't necessary.  I myself have been fiddling around for a while, but the the only completion issue I came across was the one discussed here.  I don't remember installing ```bash-completion``` on the other laptop, but that has been updated over multiple versions of Debian, so perhaps the package used to be installed by default but now no longer is.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my previous comment just before you posted your answer to it... Just for the records: I was wondering if aliasing could introduce security risks. But, in fact, if you can alias commands you can as well execute them directly,  But still, I think that protecting the .bashrc file (so that only root can modify or delete it) is a good idea (in my humble opinion...) I'll stick with it.